# C# HTML agility pack, pulling plain text from a div

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to pull short little blurbs from [site](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/) (lol).

HTML of what I am trying to pull is below.

```
<div class="field field-name-field-body-medium field-type-text-long field-label-hidden">
The community comics collaboration is back for another heaping helping of Academy fun!
</div>
```

code I am currently using that is not working.

```
var shortBio = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(p => p.Attributes.Contains("class") && p.Attributes["class"]
         .Value.Contains("field field - name - field - body - medium field - type - text - long field - label - hidden"));


 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         blurbs[i] = shortBio.ElementAt(i).ToString();
     }
```

obviously this is not working and I am not sure how to pull the text. I keep finding info on just pulling

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the parent of your target `div` is given class `teaser-content` which can be a good identifier. The following XPath should return the wanted `div` :

```
//div[@class='teaser-content']/div
```

Then you can get the content text of the `div` from `InnerText` property, for example (replace `SelectSingleNode()` with `SelectNodes()` and iterate through the result if you want *all* `div`s instead of just the first one) :

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/");
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='teaser-content']/div");
Console.WriteLine(div.InnerText);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MM0Cji)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
The community comics collaboration is back for another heaping helping of Academy fun!
```